Why is the status always pending?
I have some helps.
I developed a small project and deployed on cpanel.
by the way, whenever I send a file that is larger 130K size to upload, request status is always 'PENDING'.
of course, all are working correctly on localhost but not deployed project.
the most important thing is that I could upload very large files on online until 4 days ago.
here is my code.
// frontend
const sendFormWithToken = (httpMethod, token, data, route, callback) => {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            //console.log(e.loaded + " / " + e.total)
        }
    }
    xhr.onloadstart = function (e) {
        //console.log("start")
    }
    xhr.onloadend = function (e) {
        //console.log("end")
    }
    xhr.onload = () => {

        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
            callback(xhr, false);
        } else {
            if (xhr.status == "401") {
                window.location.replace("../home");
            }
            callback(xhr, true);
        }
    }
    xhr.open(httpMethod, serviceUrl + route, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
    xhr.send(data);
}

// backend
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: config.common.uploads,
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'file-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    limits: { fileSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024 },  // 100 MB file size limit
    storage: storage
}).array('file');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/upload', (req, res, next) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (!err) {
            controller.fileProcess(req, res, next);
        }
    });
});

I want to know where the issue is in whether cpanel or my code.
and how to fix.
